# Loop optimization by the IBM xlC compiler with Altivec

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, vectorization, xlc

I was just playing around with the Altivec extension on a power6 cluster we have.  I noticed that when I compiled the code below without any optimizations, my speedup was 4 as I was expecting.  However, when I compiled it again with the -O3 flag, I managed to obtain a speedup of 60!

Just wondering if anyone has more experience with this and is able to provide some insight into how the compiler is rearranging my code to perform such a speedup.  Is the only possible optimization through assembly and instruction pipelining here, or is there something else I am missing that I can include in my future work.

```
int main(void) {
        const int m = 1000;

        __vector signed int va;
        __vector signed int vb;
        __vector signed int vc;
        __vector signed int vd;

        int a[m];
        int b[m];
        int c[m];

        for( int i=0 ; i < m ; i++ ) {
                a[i] = i;
                b[i] = i;
                c[i] = 0;
        }

        for( int cnt = 0 ; cnt < 10000000 ; cnt++ ) {
                vd = (__vector signed int){cnt,cnt,cnt,cnt};

                for( int i = 0 ; i < m/4 ; i+=4 ) {
                        va = vec_ld(0, &a[i]);
                        vb = vec_ld(0, &b[i]);
                        vc = vec_add(vd, vec_add(va,vb));
                        vec_st(vc, 0, &c[i]);
                }
        }

        std::cout << c[0] << ", " << c[1] << ", " << c[2] << ", " << c[3] << "\n";

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've done some stuff on Power 7, and I have seen very odd things with the XLC compiler. But not as odd as this! (not 60x at least...)

One thing to note about the PowerPC series (at least for Power6 and Power7), is that the instruction latencies are very long and the out-of-order execution is very weak compared to x86/x64.

Therefore, the inner loop (as written in your code) will get extremely low IPC.

Now, the only way I can imagine you getting 60x speedup is that the inner loop is **completely unrolled under -O3**. This is possible since the trip count of the inner loop can be statically determined to be 63.

Unrolling that inner loop will basically allow the entire pipeline to be filled.

Of course I'm just guessing. Your best bet is to look at the assembly.

Also, how are you timing this? A lot of the weird behavior I've seen on PowerPC is from the timers themselves...

EDIT:

Since your sample code is fairly simple, it should be very easy to spot (in the assembly) whether or not that inner loop is partially or completely unrolled.

Comment: I've been timing this with just the "time" command in AIX.  I didn't insert any timers within the code itself.  Also, I'm a little confused why there is any IPC?  Is the work not all completed on a single thread and a single core?

Comment: Sorry, I meant IPC as in "Instructions per Cycle". I didn't realize that it also stands for Interrupts per Cycle... :) The "time" command should be fine. I've seen weirdness with clock() in some situations.